# Listview ItemSelectionChanged, How to cancel / undo

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview

If you have a look at the code below. The Listview ItemSelectionChanged event fires twice and thus I get the UserClosedSession dialog twice. Is there a way to suppress the second dialog ?

Basically, I'm trying to do some validation when user clicks on an item in a Listview. When changing the selected item, they get asked a question, if yes then go ahead and select the new item, if no then "undo" the selection. The code below is a simple sample only of the real world problem. Ignore the content of UserClosedSession, it is just used here to mimic what needs to happen.

I have tried all sorts. Tried the mouse click / mouse down events. But these are no good if the user changes selections with the keyboard. I have also tried un-wiring and then re-wiring the ItemSelectionChangedevent from withing itself (see commented out code) - doesn't work.

```
    private void lv_ItemSelectionChanged(object sender, ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.IsSelected)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Index: " + lv.SelectedIndices[0].ToString());
            if (lv.Tag != null)
            {
                if ((int)lv.Tag != lv.SelectedIndices[0])
                {

                    if (!UserClosedSession())
                    {
                        //lv.ItemSelectionChanged -= new ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventHandler(lv_ItemSelectionChanged);
                        //lv.ItemSelectionChanged -= lv_ItemSelectionChanged;
                        lv.Items[(int)lv.Tag].Selected = true;
                        //lv.ItemSelectionChanged +=new ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventHandler(lv_ItemSelectionChanged);
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
                lv.Tag = lv.SelectedIndices[0];
        }
    }


    private bool UserClosedSession()
    {
        return
            (MessageBox.Show("Close Session?", "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes);
    }
```

Comment: Why are you setting it to Selected.  Won't selecting it will select it.

Comment: Blam, I'm not setting it to select the newly selected item, I'm setting it to select the previously selected item if the user answers "No" to the dialog.

Comment: This is due to Win32's ListView having a private Timer - related to editing items - which fires after mouse selections. It has affected me several times in the past and I have never successfully worked around it.

Answer (score 0):

I have used something like this before and it worked, maybe it will for you in this situation as well.  All I am doing is setting a boolean field to hold whether a value indicating whether this event has been handled or not.  If it has not been handled, the method will run through and set handled field to true.  The next time around, it will see that this has been handled, not run through the entire method and set the handled field back to false.  This will only if the event is being fired two times in a row and you only want to handle the first event fire.  If you want the second event fire, I can help you with that.  If this event is firing off more than two times in a row, let me know, I can probably figure out a solution to that issue as well.

```
bool eventHandled = false;
private void lv_ItemSelectionChanged(object sender, ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!eventHandled)
    {
        eventHandled = true;
        if (e.IsSelected)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Index: " + lv.SelectedIndices[0].ToString());
            if (lv.Tag != null)
            {
                if ((int)lv.Tag != lv.SelectedIndices[0])
                {
                    if (!UserClosedSession())
                    {
                        //lv.ItemSelectionChanged -= new ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventHandler(lv_ItemSelectionChanged);
                        //lv.ItemSelectionChanged -= lv_ItemSelectionChanged;
                        lv.Items[(int)lv.Tag].Selected = true;
                        //lv.ItemSelectionChanged +=new ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventHandler(lv_ItemSelectionChanged);
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
                lv.Tag = lv.SelectedIndices[0];
        }
    }
    else
        eventHandled = false;
}
```